# How ID_PART_ENTRY_UUID is computed in GPT?

Tags: partition, udev, gpt, partition-table, libblkid

How the tag `ID_PART_ENTRY_UUID` is computed? Can I get `ID_PART_TABLE_UUID` from `ID_PART_ENTRY_UUID`?

I have a disk with `GPT` partition table and some partitions.

I need to identify which partitions are related to my disk. All partitions in the disk are referenced to partition table in this disk. I can found this partition table id with `udevadm`:

```
$ sudo udevadm info /dev/loop18p1 | grep ID_PART_TABLE_UUID
E: ID_PART_TABLE_UUID=75e3b937-1ff1-4166-a51f-524b98278e6e
```

However, unfortunately `udevadm` (as well as `parted` and so on) is not suitable for me and I have to use `blkid`

I can found a partition table id from disk:

```
$ sudo blkid -po udev /dev/loop18 | grep ID_PART_TABLE_UUID
ID_PART_TABLE_UUID=75e3b937-1ff1-4166-a51f-524b98278e6e
```

But `ID_PART_TABLE_UUID` is absent in partition:

```
$ sudo blkid -po udev /dev/loop18p1
ID_PART_ENTRY_SCHEME=gpt
ID_PART_ENTRY_NAME=primary
ID_PART_ENTRY_UUID=bcf5e461-90db-4625-a471-6c1d61126773
ID_PART_ENTRY_TYPE=0fc63daf-8483-4772-8e79-3d69d8477de4
ID_PART_ENTRY_NUMBER=1
ID_PART_ENTRY_OFFSET=34
ID_PART_ENTRY_SIZE=195279
ID_PART_ENTRY_DISK=7:18
```

There is only `ID_PART_ENTRY_UUID`. In `MBR` partition table, `ID_PART_ENTRY_UUID` is just a `ID_PART_TABLE_UUID` plus serial number of partition, so I can handle it easily. But in `GPT` table `ID_PART_ENTRY_UUID` is a tricky hash. I suppose this hash is related to `ID_PART_TABLE_UUID` and I can use it to recognize a partitions of disk.

So, how this hash `ID_PART_ENTRY_UUID` is computed? Can I get `ID_PART_TABLE_UUID` from `ID_PART_ENTRY_UUID`?

I suppose it's possible because `udevadm` can do it.

Upd: Actually I use binding to `liblkid` instead of CLI `blkid` but I suppose it doesn't matter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For GPT `ID_PART_TABLE_UUID` and `ID_PART_ENTRY_UUID` are not related, these are just unique UUIDs (or in fact GUIDs converted to UUIDs in libblkid) from GPT header (for `ID_PART_TABLE_UUID`) and GPT partition entry (for `ID_PART_ENTRY_UUID`).

UDev has the information simply because it has a basic parent-child relationship knowledge and for partitions some basic information from the parent (disk) are added to the partition data (see [60-persistent-storage.rules UDev rule](https://github.com/systemd/systemd/blob/master/rules.d/60-persistent-storage.rules#L15)).